# Error: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0038fd50

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have written a code using global heap. I need to redo the same operation a number of time. Every time I need to clear the heap and re-assign the data. but the vector::clear() function does not free the memory. so after some time the memory gets filled and the program terminates.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define N 30000
typedef unsigned int uint;
class Node;
class Edge;
vector<Node*> nodes;
vector<Edge*> edges;

class Node
{
public:
    Node(uint id): id(id)
    {
        nodes.push_back(this);
    }
public:
    uint id;
};

class Edge
{
public:
    Edge(int nod1, int nod2)
        : nodH(nod1), nodT(nod2)
    {
        edges.push_back(this);
    }
    bool Connects(Node* nod1, Node* nod2)
    {
        return (
            (nod1->id == this->nodH && nod2->id == this->nodT) ||
            (nod1->id == this->nodT && nod2->id == this->nodH));
    }
public:
    int nodH;
    int nodT;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Node *nd;
    for(long int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            nd = new Node(j);
        }
        for (uint j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            Edge* e = new Edge(j,N-j);
        }
        printf("%d %d ",nodes.size(),edges.size());

        // Do something here like calling function etc.
        nodes.erase(nodes.begin()+N/2);

        nodes.clear();
        edges.clear();
        //nodes.~vector();
        //edges.~vector();
        printf("%d %d\n",nodes.size(),edges.size());
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

what can I do? I tried the vector::~vector() function. But that did not work.
Can anyone help me about how to free the "cleared" memory space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well known trick is to swap your vector with temporary created one

```
template< class T >
void clearVector( std::vector< T > & v )
{ 
    std::vector< T > dummy;
    std::swap( v, dummy );
}
```

BTW, using vector with raw pointers isn't a good idea. I'll suggest [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or similar. If (in some amazing reasons) you can't use smart pointers, then you should call function like this

```
struct die {
    template <class T> void operator()( const T * p ) const { delete p; }
};
template< class InputIterator >
inline void kill_em_all( const InputIterator & begin, const InputIterator & end )
{
    std::for_each( begin, end, die() );
}

...
kill_em_all( vector_to_clear.begin(), vector_to_clear.end() );
```

Comment: I tried the following:
   **vector<Node*> temp_nod;
   vector<Edge*> temp_edg;
   swap( nodes, temp_nod );
   swap(edges,temp_edg);
   temp_nod.~vector();
   temp_edg.~vector();**
But it is still not working.

Comment: Can't understand what doesn't work... Do you want to delete all elements in vector (that was created by `Edge* e = new Edge(j,N-j);`) ?

Comment: The memory used by the program is still increasing.
The elements in the vectors are being deleted. But memory space is not being deallocated. :(

Comment: If you'll try exactly this code - http://pastebin.com/sbARHU8P - you'll get bad_alloc, but, if you'll uncomment last 4 lines, it will work OK till the end

Answer (score 0):

The reason `vector.clear()` does not delete the objects is that you keep raw pointers in the two vectors:

```
vector<Node*> nodes;
vector<Edge*> edges;
```

You either have to deallocate the elements yourself or, better, use smart pointers (for example, `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: Is there any way out? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning one giant heap of memory for your application. Try to reduce your `N` to 100 for the start. `bad_alloc` usually means, that the runtime was not able to reserve memory.

Comment: I know that. But I need large amount of data.